# Backup without using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup

I am trying to take a backup on a Windows Server 2003 and SQL Server 2005 installed on it. But, there is no SQL Server Management Studio on it. How can I take full backup of a particular database.

Comment: [`sqlcmd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to run your backup script

Comment: In addition, if you have SSMS installed on your desktop (and you have sufficient rights) you can issue the command from your desktop.

Comment: I would second running the backup via ssms on your desktop unless you can't for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sqlcmd from the command prompt.

It's default location for SQL 2012 is here :- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn

For windows authentication run :- sqlcmd -SSERVERNAME

or for sql authentication run:- sqlcmd -SSERVERNAME -ULogin -PPassword

You can then run a backup sql statement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx

Comment: Needs moar PowerShell

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you want to run it in powershell?

Comment: Just being obnoxious. ;) I'd have gone `sqlcmd` route myself but was just pointing out the capability and infatuation with PS many DBAs have

Comment: PS is the way to go, Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance servername -Database databasename

Comment: 2005 doesn't like Backup-SqlDatabase : Backup to URL device is not supported on server version 9.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Try this in command promt

In winodws authentication mode

```
SQLCMD -E -S SERVERNAME -Q "BACKUP DATABASE DatabaseName TO DISK='D:\Backup\DatabaseName.bak'"
```

In Sql Authentication mode

```
SQLCMD -S SERVERNAME -U sqlUser -P Password
```

then run the `BACKUP DATABASE DatabaseName TO DISK='D:\Backup\DatabaseName.bak'` in next step